# InvalidOperationException: No columns were selected when performing a DELETE query

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I have the feeling I'm missing something obvious, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

```
public async Task Delete(Guid id) {
  using (var db = _connectionFactory()) {
    try {
      await db.QueryAsync("DELETE FROM ...", new { id}).ConfigureAwait(false);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      Console.WriteLine(exception);
      throw;
    }
  }
}
```

So when this piece of code gets executed, I get the exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No columns were selected
```

Even though I don't need anything back from my call. I just want to know whether or not my DELETE query has succeeded. The strange part is that the query does get executed. The relevant record is deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I suspected. It was something stupid. Solution:

```
await db.ExecuteAsync("DELETE FROM ...", new { id}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```